# drop user ORA-00604 and ORA-00054

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I execute a impdp, but it does not finish because there isnt space in tablespace.

I stop the impdb and now i Need drop the new schema and I use this command:

```
SQL> drop user TEST cascade;
drop user TGK_EXOR_IFIL_008_432 cascade
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired
```

I dont find any lock on database for this schema:

```
SQL> select * from v$session where username = 'TEST';

no rows selected
```

I use oracle 11g

Comment: Try to select * from v$session **without**  where username = 'TEST', what would be the output? Looks like Oracle is rolling back the changes and you should wait untill it finish. Also, check longops:    SELECT VSL.TIME_REMAINING,
       VS.SQL_FULLTEXT,
       VSL.*
  FROM V$SESSION_LONGOPS VSL
  LEFT JOIN V$SQL VS
    ON VS.SQL_ID = VSL.SQL_ID
 WHERE TIME_REMAINING > 0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The impdp was either still running or it was rolling back the import itself.
You can try and wait for it to finish or kill it manually. Find it with this:

```
select o.object_name as "object_name",
       s.sid as "sid",
       s.serial# as "serial#",
       s.username as "username",
       sq.sql_fulltext as "sql_fulltext"
  from v$locked_object l, dba_objects o, v$session s,
       v$process p, v$sql sq
  where l.object_id = o.object_id
    and l.session_id = s.sid and s.paddr = p.addr
    and s.sql_address = sq.address;
```

[credit](http://www.oraclebytes.com/checking-for-locks-to-get-rid-of-that-pesky-ora-00054/)
After finding the object that is locked you can kill the sid.
Or if a table is holding it up you can mark it read only:

```
alter table table_name read only;
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue in an Oracle 12c database and got it resolved like this:

Connect to the database using command prompt:

```
sql> sys as sydba
(enter password)
```

Run

```
sql>@catqueue.sql under C:\app\dbuser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\RDBMS\ADMIN
```

(Possibly adapting the path to your `ADMIN` directory.)

Then run

```
drop user xxxx cascade;
```

This should be able to drop the user.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33483233)